# Steps to create a simple JPA code

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I am new to `Eclipse/Java world and to JPA` as well, but I have read all the basics of how to use and all.

I get it that `JPA` is *framework which helps to map the objects to relation databases* but in layman terms how do we create a DB to support it and how to create a sample program. I have followed a lot on internet where exact code is given but no where told how to create the database or the connection for it?

I have tried to install `JBoss Tools for Hibernate support` but I can't get a simple example out of it. I have the code to run but can't figure out how to configure the db connection and how to join it with the code?

Can anyone please guide me ahead.

Comment: if you are going with hubernate, try this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/

Comment: try this site, here you'll find an example, www.tkhts.com

Comment: @user902383 what are the other options that I can use? Easy & quick way?

Comment: @SumitGupta My setup of eclipse is fresh & I dont think I already have any db sw installed. Do I need to install MySQL first? How do I create the table for it?

Comment: @Raj - of course you'll need a database, an ORM connects to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this link

http://www.tkhts.com/orm-tools/hibernate/index.jsp

they have videos and screenshots and code available.

I hope it'll be really helpful. And it's all done with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

A better and more complete documentation you can find at:
http://www.hibernate.org/docs.html

Examples of initial settings for Hibernate / database you can use this document:
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Start with some JPA book, **Pro EJB 3.0 - Persistence API**  is good choice.